# SSIS Packages with Excel Source Intermittently Failing - Started Failing in May 2023

Tags: ssis

I have several SSIS packages that import data from Excel into SQL Server.  These packages have been working perfectly for over a year.  About 2 weeks ago they started failing, but only intermittently.  I just tested one of them 10 times in a row and it failed 5 of those times.  The error messages it gives me are as follows (only the rows from the first to the last error are pasted here):

Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER. The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "SourceConnectionExcel" failed with error code 0xC0202009. There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
Error: Source - Inventory_Detail_Data$ failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
Progress: Validating - 100 percent complete
Error: One or more component failed validation.
Error:  There were errors during task validation.
Validation is completed
Finished, 10:09:33 AM, Elapsed tme: 00:00:03.282
Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB records is available. Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description "External table is not in the expected format.".

I am 99% sure the "External table is not in the expected format" message is incorrect, as this is happening on 12 different packages connected to 12 different Excel files.  It is very unlikely that all of these Excel tables have had a format change and I do not see any such format change.  Furthermore, the package completes successfully sometimes, if there was a format change it would seem that the package would always fail.

I also tried re-creating the SSIS package from scratch and get the exact same result (sometimes it works, sometimes it fails).

As stated above, these packages all used to work correctly.  Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: I've had a similar issue with an ODBC connection over the last couple of weeks. It had a similar connection manager issue. I ended up changing the connection so it was using an sql open query in an oledb connection (which has native for the ssis server) and it worked. I was thinking that some kind of Microsoft update might haver thrown something out. I can only suggest tying a different connection and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: @A.Steer Thank you for the suggestion.  Can you provide more information about how to do this or send a link?  I tried selecting "Data sources" that mention sql and OLE DB, but they all seem to be expecting a db or server as input, not an Excel file:

Comment: If you can save the excel file as a cab, you should then be able to use a flat file connection to import the data

Comment: @A.Steer  I tried with cab extension and flat file connection and it came through as unreadable gobbledygook:  "R�G.�-�\�"

Comment: Sorry that was an autocorrect error. If you save the file as a .CSV (comma separated file) and then use the flat file connection

Comment: @A.Steer  Thanks, that is an option!  I'd rather not have to convert these files to csv every day, but that may be the best way.  I'm still holding out hope though...

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved itself.  After about 3 weeks of just living with this error it suddenly ceased about 2 weeks ago.  Nothing changed in the packages, sources, or destination.  Perhaps an OS update quietly fixed something...

Comment: Were you able to confirm that this fix came from an update to the OS? If so, was it the database/ETL server? Desktop environment?

I'm asking because we are having similar issues across numerous jobs and are desperate for a solution.

Comment: I was not able to confirm why or how the issue resolved.  Our IT department handles all updates and they were as surprised as me that it became resolved.  I so sorry I don't have any real answers to this :(